# Angular 2 highcharts final setup

Tags: angular, npm, highcharts, rxjs

After setting up a project with the latest/final Angular 2 Version, I'm not able to implement a simple highchart component depending on the tutorials into it - I've made a linechart component directory in which I would like to set up my chart and then add it into the project-sites by using the `<line-chart></line-chart>` tag in the html.

my **linechart.component.ts**

```
import {Component} from "@angular/core";
import { CHART_DIRECTIVES } from 'angular2-highcharts';

@Component({
  selector:"app-linechart",
  templateUrl:"./linechart.component.html",
  directives: [CHART_DIRECTIVES],
  styles: [`
      chart {
        display: block;
      }
    `]

})
export class LinechartComponent{
  constructor() {
    this.options = {
      title : { text : 'example chart' },
      series: [{
        type: 'column',
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2],
      }]
    };
  }
  options: Object;
}
```

**app.component.html**

```
   ...
     <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-6">
        <app-linechart></app-linechart>
      </div>
    </div>
...
```

**Console Errors: (paths shortened)**

> Uncaught Error: Cannot find module "rxjs/observable/of" main.bundle.js:22045
>
> ./~/@angular/router/src/router.js
>       Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'rxjs/observable/of' in '/node_modules/@angular/router/src'
>       resolve 'rxjs/observable/of' in 'node_modules/@angular/router/src'
>         Parsed request is a module
>         using description file: /node_modules/@angular/router/package.json (relative path: ./src)
>           Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
>         after using description file: //node_modules/@angular/router/package.json (relative path: ./src)
>           resolve as module
>                   .../node_modules/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory doesn't exist or is not a directory
>                  .../node_modules/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory/node_modules/@angular/router/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
>                  .../node_modules/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory/node_modules/@angular/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
>             .../node_modules/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
>             looking for modules in ...

**app.module.ts**

```
...
import { OverviewComponent } from './sites/overview/overview.component';
import {ChartModule}            from 'angular2-highcharts';
import { Ng2Highcharts } from 'ng2-highcharts';

 ... imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    routing,
    ChartModule,
    Ng2Highcharts
  ],
```

I followed all the steps on [ng2-highcharts](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-highcharts)` and tried [angular2-highcharts](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-highcharts) (not quite sure which one is the deprecated?). Anyone experienced with that? I'm running out of ideas.

Comment: You can try ng2-charts instead. About this error: "Uncaught Error: Cannot find module "rxjs/observable/of" main.bundle.js:22045". Did you import 'rxjs' ?

Comment: rxjs is imported and part of the app.module.ts imports

Comment: Try import it like this:
import 'rxjs/Rx'; You shouldnt see this error, if you import it properly

Comment: thanks! are you experienced with setting up the charts.js into angular2? i get the following error: `..caused by: ng2-charts configuration issue: Embedding Chart.js lib is mandatory` - i know i must add the following line into my project `<script src="node_modules/chart.js/src/chart.js"></script>` but which file? index.html, component.template.html, or app.component.html?

Comment: Try to add this:
.chart {display: block; width: 100%;} to your css, there where you have chart called in template.

Comment: nevermind. solved it by adding `import 'chart.js/src/chart.js';` to my modules.ts

Answer (score 1):

For Ionic 2

add

```
import 'chart.js/src/chart.js';
```

to src/app/app.module.ts file instead of

```
<script src="node_modules/chart.js/src/chart.js"></script>
```

Thanks @edamerau